# How to fast lookup by list of indices?

Tags: pandas

Given a list of candidate indices

```
candidates = np.array([ 3, 4, 5 ])
```

You can lookup in your dataframe `df` via

```
df.loc[ candidates ]
```

However if there is a candidate missing in `df.index` this will throw an exception.
What is the the *fastest* way to obtain both?:

- the slice of `df` for all candidates that are in the index
- A boolean array indicating which candidate is in the index

Especially if `df.index.is_monotonic == True`, this fact should be used to speed things up.

Comment: Are you asking for something like `df.index.isin(candidates)` and `candidates(df.index.isin(candidates))`?

Comment: Not exactly. Computing `df.index.isin(candidates)` is unecessary if I only need to know which candidates are valid indices to `df`. Imagine `df.index` being huge, and `candidates` small. It is enough to iterate over `candidates` not over `df.index`.

Answer (score 0):

As a benchmark,the `df.size` is about 6.8M.

```
%time df.index.isin([45,66,77,99,87,65,234,668,798])
Wall time: 15 ms
array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

My suggestion

```
%%time 
item_list = [45,66,77,99,87,65,234,668,798]
result_list = []
for item in item_list:
    if item in user_shop_df.index.values:
        result_list.append(True)
    else:
        result_list.append(False)
Wall time: 10 ms
```